# What do numbers with equality statements in the WHERE clause mean in SQL (WHERE 2>1)?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I was looking at the Rails guides, and in the section to protect against SQL injections they state a hacker could inject the following code ([source](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection)):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = '' OR '1'='1' AND password = '' OR '2'>'1' LIMIT 1
```

It says in the Rails guide that:

> This will simply find the first record in the database, and grants
>   access to this user.

Can someone explain what is the overall term used in SQL to describe number queries (so I know how to google more info), and how does it work in the above example to bypass authentication?

Comment: This is the wrong way to protect against SQL injections.  Parameters are key -- are are fully encrypted passwords.

Comment: Right, I suppose when I figure more about SQL, I'll be more qualified to make an assessment on that, but right now I'm more curious on how the above example bypasses user authentication as well as what is the term used to describe number queries in SQL are called.

Comment: Number queries?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I thought they were number queries before, but now I know them to be boolean statements, thanks to the answerer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your initial SQL to check password was:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = 'LOGIN' AND password = 'PASSWORD' LIMIT 1
```

The user can pass LOGIN = "' OR '1'='1" and PASSWORD = "' OR '2'>'1"

This will make your SQL statement as below:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE
login = '' OR '1'='1' AND password = '' OR '2'>'1' LIMIT 1
```

Let's break down there `WHERE` clause from the SQL.

> login = '' OR '1'='1' AND password = '' OR '2'>'1'
>
> (login = '' OR '1'='1') AND (password = '' OR '2'>'1')

login = '' will probably be false, but 1 = 1 will always be true.
Same for password = '' will be false, but 2 > 1 will always be true.
So we get:

> (false OR true) AND (false OR true)

That's always true. So with LIMIT at the end, you'll get 1 record from the table.

Basically, because of the injection of SQL from the variable LOGIN, the person can change the logic of the SQL Query so that he doesn't need to know the password of the user or even the username to get the query to return one row which probably will result in a successful login.

Comment: Oh so it's boolean statement. It checks whether the WHERE clause is true, then grabs the first item from the database?

Comment: Yes. On a valid scenario, (meaning someone not trying to break the system) you would have the login and password in the variables and the where condition would only return true if both matched any row in the database. This would validate both the username and the password to be matching from what is in the database. But because of the reason above, you should not use this and utilize parameters.